# Tranfer Field Values using Field ID

Tags: php, forms

i am using the following code to pass the field values using $post, with field name code work fine but i need to use field id, but i cant find a solution in to modify the code, any idea

thanks

```
<?php


/***************************
Sample using a PHP array
****************************/



require('fpdm.php');

$fields = array(
'name' => $_POST['name'],
'name1' => $_POST['name'],

);

$pdf = new FPDM('forms/template.pdf');
$pdf->Load($fields, false); // second parameter: false if field values are in ISO-8859-1, true if UTF-8
$pdf->Merge();
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: send in post array `$_POST['id']` same as $_POST['name'] ?

Comment: Hello you mean on this way? $_POST['awf-ID12']=> $_POST['name'],

Comment: no, in your html input fields you send id from there and in `$fields['id'] = $_POST['id']` if that's what you want to do.

Comment: sorry as 'name' => $_POST['awf-ID12'],?

Comment: sure, you can try it, use `var_dump($fields);` to see the output

Comment: Thanks Omar Abbas